# OpenBSD Wireless Bridge, outbound traffic gets no response

Tags: openbsd, wireless-bridge

So fun times this weekend trying to build a simple OpenBSD bridge for my XBox360. I want my ural network card to be bridged with my re network card to forward some traffic. Bleh.

I essentially cloned everything from http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#Bridge but changed the device names and the fancy wireless setup.

The system connects to my Wifi router, grabs an IP, the bridge is up as far as I can tell (pftop says packets are getting through from one interface to another), all is wonderfulish.

Problem is, I get NO response from DHCP, or anything for that matter comming back into the bridge. Why am I getting no responses (including telnet into my router's web interface)?

Configs are as follows (or close anyhow, doing this from memory):

bridgename.bridge0:

```
re0
ural0
up
```

hostname.ural0: (Names and passworkds have been changed to protect the innocent)

```
dhcp              \
nwid   'blah'     \
wpapsk 'passverd' \
```

hostname.re0:

```
up
```

pf.conf:

```
pass in  quick on ural0 all
pass out quick on ural0 all
pass in  quick on re0   all
pass out quick on re0   all
```

rc.conf:

Some stuff about routing is turned on (this was after failure, and really routing shouldn't need to be done on a bridge anyway).

I mean, it should be brain-dead simple. Why is this thing being such a huge pain?! I've done this in Linux once and that worked fine. Stupid everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible for a wireless interface to participate in a bridge unless operating in `hostap` mode. Ref threads ["Wireless bridge"](http://marc.info/?t=115196645900001&r=1&w=2) and ["Wireless bridge setup"](http://marc.info/?t=113023696500001&r=1&w=2) on openbsd-misc.

To understand why, and how this can sometimes be achieved in Linux, you can [read this](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge#It_doesn.27t_work_with_my_Wireless_card.21).

Comment: That's incredibly sad. Well, I guess it's time to brush up on my routing again (I do really enjoy OpenBSD).

Comment: It is a shame. Nor can it do WDS. You certainly can solve it with routing, sadly just not as simply as with bridging. You'll need to setup port forwards between the subnets for your inbound Xbox traffic. Kudos for sticking with OBSD nonetheless.